# Pairwise Operations in R

Tags: r

I need to calculate pairwise, *consecutive* correlations for each of these date variables (there are 246 in my dataset):

```
Company   2009/08/21      2009/08/24       2009/08/25
A       -0.0019531250   -0.0054602184    -6.274510e-03
AA      -0.0063291139   -0.0266457680    -1.750199e-02
AAPL     0.0084023598   -0.0055294118    -1.770643e-04 ...
...
```

So that I can find cor(col1,col2), cor(col2,col3), but nothing for cor(col1,col3).  I realize that if I wanted all combinations I could use the combn function, but I can't figure out how to do it for my circumstances without something inefficient like a for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach 1**
you could do:

```
lapply(1:(ncol(dat)-1), function(i) cor(dat[, i], dat[, i+1],   
   use="pairwise.complete.obs"))
```

**Example**
A dataframe with 10 variables will give you 9 consecutive correlations, i.e. columns 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 etc, if that is what you want.

```
dat <- replicate(10, rnorm(10))
lapply(1:(ncol(dat)-1), function(i) 
    cor(dat[, i], dat[, i+1], use="pairwise.complete.obs"))
```

**Approach 2 (very concise)**

Using the iris dataset as well:

```
dat <- iris[, 1:4]

diag(cor(dat, use="pairwise.complete.obs")[, -1])
[1] -0.1175698 -0.4284401  0.9628654
```

Comment: Your solution is very succinct, but for some reason I obtain NA for all of the correlations when I try it out on my dataset

Comment: Maybe bacause you a column contains NAs. See my edit.

Comment: I really like your **Approach 2** +1!

Comment: Thanks, I was surprised as well it was so simple :D

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, `combn` is the way to go. Assume your data.frame is called `dat` then for consecutive columns, try this:

```
ind <- combn(ncol(dat), 2)
consecutive <- ind[ , apply(ind, 2, diff)==1]
lapply(1:ncol(consecutive), function(i) cor(dat[,consecutive[,i]]))
```

Consider this simple example:

```
> data(iris)
> dat <- iris[, 1:4]
> # changing colnames to see whether result is for consecutive columns
> colnames(dat) <- 1:ncol(dat)  
> head(dat)   # this is how the data looks like
    1   2   3   4
1 5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2
2 4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2
3 4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2
4 4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2
5 5.0 3.6 1.4 0.2
6 5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4
> 
> ind <- combn(ncol(dat), 2)
> consecutive <- ind[ , apply(ind, 2, diff)==1]
> lapply(1:ncol(consecutive), function(i) cor(dat[,consecutive[,i]])) # output: cor matrix
[[1]]
           1          2
1  1.0000000 -0.1175698
2 -0.1175698  1.0000000

[[2]]
           2          3
2  1.0000000 -0.4284401
3 -0.4284401  1.0000000

[[3]]
          3         4
3 1.0000000 0.9628654
4 0.9628654 1.0000000
```

If you want just the correlation, use `sapply`

```
> sapply(1:ncol(consecutive), function(i) cor(dat[,consecutive[,i]])[2,1])
[1] -0.1175698 -0.4284401  0.9628654
```

Comment: But how would that not return the correlation for every pairwise combination?

Comment: Maybe I get this wrong, but this approach includes `cor(col1,col3)` as well, i.e. also not consecutive ones, does it not?

Comment: @user3103499 see my edit, Mark you're right, I fixed that problem

Answer (score 1):

Usually, loops in R should be avoided, but I think they sometimes have an undeserved stigma. In this case, the loop is easier for me to read than "cooler" functions. It's also fairly efficient. Any call like `cor(mydata)` calculates n^2 correlations, while the for loop only calculates n correlations.

```
x = matrix( rnorm(246*20000), nrow=246 )
out = numeric(245)

system.time( { for( i in 1:245 )
                 out[i] = cor(x[,i],x[,i+1]) } )
# 0.022 Seconds

system.time( diag(cor(x, use="pairwise.complete.obs")[, -1]) )
# Goes for 2 minutes and then crashes my R session
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll assume your data is stored in `df`.

Here's what I'd do. First create a function that for any given column number it will calculate the correlation between that column and the one up from it like this

```
cor.neighbour <- function(i) {
    j <- i + 1
    cr <- cor(df[, i], df[, j])

    # returning a dataframe here will make sense when you see the results from sapply
    result <- data.frame(
        x = names(df)[i],
        y = names(df)[j],
        cor = cr,
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )

    return(result)
}
```

Then to apply it to your whole data I would first create a vector of all the columns I want to use, `i` which, by the way, is all but the last column. Then use `lapply` to process through them

```
i <- 1:(ncol(df) - 1)
cor.pairs <- lapply(i, cor.neighbour)
# change list in to a data frame
cor.pairs <- melt(cor.pairs, id=names(cor.pairs[[1]]))
```